# git push to local ssh server fails a couple of times then succeeds

Tags: linux, git, ssh, server, push

I'm trying to setup a git server for a lan network which comprises a handful of workstations(Windows) and a NAS connected by a router. 
The server itself is a dedicated Ubuntu machine with `ubuntu-desktop`, `openssh` and `git` installed, which has been given a static local ip. It also mounts a folder from the NAS to hold the repos, to the directory `/media/repos`; the mounting seems to work properly.
On the windows workstations I installed "Git for windows".
I made a group, `gitusers`, and assigned proper permissions to it for the `/media/repos` directory.
Then I created 2 new ubuntu users, setting up `ssh` connections from their respective workstation  (I started with 2 only for testing, but in my idea each workstation in the local network should have its own user to ssh to). I also assigned these users to the `gitusers` group.
After that I made a bare repo on the server, inside the `/media/repos/testproject1` directory:

```
git init --bare --shared=group
```

On the workstations I successfully cloned the repo like this:

```
git clone firstuser@192.168.1.47:/media/repos/testproject1
```

Everything seem to work fine until I `push`:

```
$ git push
Counting objects: 3, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (2/2), done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 331 bytes | 331.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 3 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: error: unable to create temporary file: Operation not permitted
remote: fatal: failed to write object
error: remote unpack failed: unpack-objects abnormal exit
To 192.168.1.47:/media/repos/testproject1
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (unpacker error)
error: failed to push some refs to 'firstuser@192.168.1.47:/media/repos/testproject1'
```

But then if I try to `push` again for a couple of times it suddenly succeeds:

```
Counting objects: 3, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (2/2), done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 331 bytes | 331.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 3 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
To 192.168.1.47:/media/repos/testproject1
   ba2b2a7..a798d28  master -> master
```

Once the push succeeds, I can pull/clone/fetch the updated repo seemingly without issue. Of course the push command still remains problematic.
I fear the problem might by in the mounted NAS folder, like described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24173942/9072069
But this answer itself suggests setting up an ssh server to avoid the problem... isn't that what I just did?
Thanks.

**edit:** Just for clarification, the network configuration is like this:

```
    N---R---+---+---+---
            |   |   |
            W   W   S
```

where N=NAS, R=router, W=workstation (there are more than 2), S=server.
From the workstations I execute the git commands like this (`192.168.1.47` is the ip of the server):

```
git x user@192.168.1.47:path-to-repo
```

The NAS has been mounted on the server by editing the file `/etc/fstab` with something like this (where `1001` is the id of group `gitgroup`):

```
//192.168.1.47/share /media/repos cifs credentials=/home/username/.smbcredentials,iocharset=utf8,gid=*1001*,uid=*1000*,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777 0 0
```

Comment: So the repository is on a shared drive?  Any particular reason you are not using a traditional ssh-access repository on your ubuntu host?

Comment: Yes, the repository is on a shared drive which is mounted onto the ubuntu server, because the internal hdd of the server is very small. I don't know what you mean with "traditional ssh-access"? As far as I understand (very little honestly) I'm already using ssh to access the ubuntu server.

Comment: From your wording I understood that the Ubuntu server exposed a shared drive where everybody could access the git repository directly.  Apparently that was incorrect.   If at all possible, could you remove the NAS from the equation because I think that is the problem - for instance not doing locks correctly?  Add an extra drive or use another machine?  If you can run virtual machines, that would be an option too.